# Which database for a huge list of one type of data?

Tags: python, database, redis, nosql

A python script I write generates IDs that I need to add to a list, while another script checks, if the ID already exists in the list. There are no other tables, relations or anything, just a huge, growing list of 6-letter strings. I need to add and read values as fast as possible at the same time. What would be the database of choice in that case? A NoSQL database like redis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis is a perfect fit for this,  you can use redis hashes. Also ensure you shard hashes for efficiency see below link for more details on how instagram reduces the total memory requirements by using redis hashes.

https://instagram-engineering.com/storing-hundreds-of-millions-of-simple-key-value-pairs-in-redis-1091ae80f74c

Comment: In my case I wouldn't even have a key value pair, just a list of values. And not a lot of RAM (2gb). Is redis still the best choice then?

Comment: Yes it is still a best choice,  use empty values.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, MongoDB or Redis, can do the work